# Getting a class not found error on org/jdesktop/swingx/plaf/ComponentAddon

Tags: java, swingx

I added my first swingX component (a JXTable) to my project, hoping to enjoy its extended features.

After a lot of searching I found the swingX 1.6.5-1 jar [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadswingxcore1651sourcesjar.htm).

The imports work fine and I don't have any compilation errors. However, runtime instantiation of the JXtable throws a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/swingx/plaf/ComponentAddon"
error.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler on a windows 8.1 machine with JDK 1.6.0.38 as the project builder.

Your ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I downloaded the wrong jar. Shouldv'e downloaded swingx-all.